# Show items with no data when filtering by field

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, no-data

Is there a way of filtering using a field but still keep showing items which don't have a value?

I have prepared a quick dummy test:
[image: PowerBi capture]

On the left, when i filter by "indicator name" by 'This' and 'that' values, countries with no data on either categories disappear. On the right, when it's not filtered, we see other countries even if they have no data. My problem is that I actually have a hundred indicators, that is why i need to filter that.

'Show items without data' has been already marked.
Is there a way around the filter to show all countries?

Model looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work-around is to create a Measure and adding "+0".